# Is it against rules to ask new users to mark answer as complete once you've answered their questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm just being safe here, and checking I'm not violating any rules.

I see lots of users with 1 rep asking questions, saying "Thanks it worked!" but not marking the answer as answered.

Is it acceptable to kindly comment "Okay mark as answered if it worked :)" after they say "Thanks that worked!"?

Ruby

Comment: Yes @JoshCaswell my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I actually see this happening a lot (people asking to set it as a answer) I also have never seen someone getting a punishment for this. Anyhow if that is the correct answer isn't it better that it got accepted?